# Equivalence command basename and dirname linux in powershell

Tags: powershell-5.0

Powershell: 5.0

Hi!

How powershell get basename from file with "." in name?

And for a dir ?

- Example:

```
Filename: test.txt
dir: /test01.test/
```

- Desired result:

```
Filename: test
dir: test01
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not what basename in linux does, unless you specify the suffix:

```
basename /users/js/file.txt
file.txt

basename file.txt .txt               
file
```

However here's a way to do what you want.  It prints out the basename property of the fileinfo or dirinfo object.  % is short for foreach-object.

```
get-item file.txt | % basename
file
```

Comment: Actually, `(Get-Item file.txt).basename` will also work nicely.